# Regex for Text Field in Flow screen input validation gives error

Tags: formula, visual-workflow, regular-expressions

```
REGEX( {!Phone} , "((^[?+\+\s]|^[\d]?)([\s\-\.]?)([\d]{1,3})([\s\-\.\(]*)([\d]{3})([\s\-\.\)]*)([\d]{3})([\s\-\.]*)([\d]{4})$)" )
```

> Phone (Screen Component) - The formula expression is invalid: Syntax
>   error

What is wrong here? I copy paste `((^[?+\+\s]|^[\d]?)([\s\-\.]?)([\d]{1,3})([\s\-\.\(]*)([\d]{3})([\s\-\.\)]*)([\d]{3})([\s\-\.]*)([\d]{4})$)` in regex checker and it seems ok, but in salesforce syntax error?

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape your backslashes. Anywhere you have one backslash (`\`), replace it with two (`\\`).

Comment: `REGEX( {!Phone} , "((^[?+\\+\\s]|^[\\d]?)([\\s\\-\\.]?)([\\d]{1,3})([\\s\\-\\.\\(]*)([\\d]{3})([\\s\\-\\.\\)]*)([\\d]{3})([\\s\\-\\.]*)([\\d]{4})$)" )`
As you mention I replace all \ with \\ and it worked. thank you.